# Swift: Multiple intervals in single switch-case using tuple

Tags: ios, swift, switch-statement, tuples, xcode6

Have a code like:

```
switch (indexPath.section, indexPath.row) {
    case (0, 1...5): println("in range")
    default: println("not at all")
}
```

**The question is can I use multiple intervals in second tuple value?**

for non-tuple switch it can be done pretty easily like

```
switch indexPath.section {
case 0:
    switch indexPath.row {
    case 1...5, 8...10, 30...33: println("in range")
    default: println("not at all")
    }
default: println("wrong section \(indexPath.section)")
}
```

Which separator should I use to separate my intervals inside tuple or it's just not gonna work for tuple switches and I have to use switch inside switch? Thanks!

Answer (score 150, accepted):

You have to list multiple tuples at the top level:

```
switch (indexPath.section, indexPath.row) {
    case (0, 1...5), (0, 8...10), (0, 30...33):
        println("in range")
    case (0, _):
        println("not at all")
    default:
        println("wrong section \(indexPath.section)")
}
```

Comment: Works perfect! Thank you so much! Can't understand now how I didn't figured it out! Thank you!

Comment: It is important to put your most restrictive cases first if you're not using `fallthrough` statements on them. The switch evaluates the cases from top to bottom, not by which one matches perfectly.

Comment: this is awesome! Where did you find this in doc ?

Comment: @drewag Is that possible using `let` or `var` in single case?