# switch statement with ints

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to get a simple switch statement using two variables at the same time, however I keep getting a ton of errors and I don't really know how to syntax it properly. All I want to know is if one is/isnt zero and the other one is or isn't zero. My code is as follows:

```
    var ptsRemaining: Int?
    var ptsUsed: Int = 0

func updatedButtons() {
        switch (ptsRemaining, ptsUsed) {
        case (0), (0):
            print("do thing 1")
        case (0), (!0):
            print("do thing 2")
        case (!0), (0):
            print("do thing 3")
        case (!0), (!0):
            print("do thing 4")
        default:
            print("error!")
        }
    }
```

NOTE I ALSO TRIED THIS :

```
func updatedButtons() {
        switch (ptsRemaining, ptsUsed) {
        case (0,0):
            print("hello")
        case (0,!0):
            print("hello")
        case (!0,0):
            print("hello")
        case (!0,!0): 
            print("hello")
        default:
            print("Error")
        }
    }
```

In both cases the errors I receive are the following:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'Bool'
Expression pattern of type 'Int' cannot match values of type 'Int?'
```

Comment: Isn't it `case (0, 0):`? Also, you're missing a closing parenthesis at `print("error!"`

Comment: I was looking over at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25165123/swift-multiple-intervals-in-single-switch-case-using-tuple and they do (thing), (thing) instead of (thing, thing) . Tried it anyways and still get errors

Comment: @dvd.Void If you write it like that, the commas mean "or".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't say "not 0" by doing `!0`. This is not an if statement. This is pattern matching.

To match the pattern of "anything", you need to use `_` aka the wildcard pattern.

```
switch (ptsRemaining, ptsUsed) {
case (0?, 0):
    print("do thing 1")
case (0?, _):
    print("do thing 2")
case (_, 0):
    print("do thing 3")
default: // you don't need the case of "both not 0"
    print("do thing 4")
}
```

But you shouted, "I don't want to match 'anything'! I want to match 'not 0'!".

Well, switch cases are matched in order. If the first case does not match, then one or more of the variables must not be 0! Then we see if the first one is 0 and at this point we don't care about the second variable because we know it must not be 0 if the first one is 0. Same goes for the third case.

Note that if you want to treat `nil` as 0, you can do this:

```
switch (ptsRemaining ?? 0, ptsUsed)
```

and then remove the `?`s in the cases.

Comment: This throws an error when `ptsRemaining` is optional as per the question

Comment: @tomsterritt use case (0?, 0)

Comment: @tomsterritt Edited.

Comment: @Sweeper, Just a  quick question, how would you check for a negative value? like -_ or >0 (but this is boolean so I'm sure its wrong

Comment: @dvd.Void then you need to use the where clause like shallowThought did in their answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the `where` statement:

```
var ptsRemaining: Int?
var ptsUsed: Int = 0

func updatedButtons() {
    switch (ptsRemaining, ptsUsed) {
    case (0?, 0):
        print("do thing 1")
    case (0?, let second) where second != 0:
        print("do thing 2")
    case (let first, 0) where first != 0:
        print("do thing 3")
    default:
        print("both not 0")
    }
}
```

Comment: well I had 4 If statements that were getting lengthy and I thought a switch statement would be a better choice

Comment: I would like to upvote for showing containing with where. but the conclusion that switch isn't the right tool is too far-fetched.

Comment: OK, removed opinion based conclusion.